# PHP - Sonar - Remove this unused private method

Tags: php, sonarqube

In my PHP code, there are some private methods, I don't call them directly, I call them dynacally by method string instead.

Sonar reported that 
"Remove this unused private "blahblah" method" with Major level.

I have no idea to fix this issue.

Please give an advice.

Thank for your help.

Comment: In this case (as far as I know) you able only disable rule in sonar(

Comment: <pre>
<code>

class Foo {
    public function good_job() {
        # blah blah
        $method_name = '_bar';
        $this->$method_name();
    }

    /*
    * My project structure love using private method and invoke by call by string.
    * But Sonar doesn't love it.
    */
    private function _bar () {
        # blah blah
    }
}
</pre>
</code>

MHRasel:   FYI
VladimirKovpak Nice, I'll try to request for removing this rule.

Answer (score 2):

The rule `Unused "private" methods should be removed` of SonarPHP has the following exceptions:

1. Constructor
2. Method starting with '__'
3. Method name present in one of the string literals of the class declaration scope

So, if the class declaration contains one string literal that contains the method name, SonarPHP don't report any issue about unused method.

Example:

```
    class Foo {
      public function foo() {
        $method_name = '_bar';
        $this->$method_name();
      }
      private function _bar() { // OK - used in a string literal of the class Foo
      }
    }
```